# How to run a simple main method and copy the file it generated using docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I have a simple main method that outputs a folder with some files.
How do i copy the file to my host to view the output files. Tried using volume but it didnt work out. Here is the docker file

`FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD main.jar main.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","main.jar"]`

//generated folder 'xxxx' with some files.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your `docker run` command as well?

Comment: Where does your main.jar output files/folders ?

Comment: Perhaps [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)?

Answer (score 0):

The way to make files available outside the container is with a volume mapping. To make the files available in your current directory you would do `docker run -v $PWD:/tmp .... yourimage`